# an error has occurred.see log file. workspace .metadata .log eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jess

I am using the eclipse INDIGO(Version: 3.7.1).if i try to open the jess.clp file in my project(that was newly created jess file), then it will close the eclipse and show like this."an error has occurred.see log file. \workspace.metadata.log"

i deleted the .metadata folder and the restart the eclipse. it will show the same kind of thing.

.log show like this

```
   !SESSION 2019-08-09 20:17:30.206 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.8.0_92
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2019-08-09 20:17:32.784
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-08-09 20:17:39.207
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early for part org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early for part org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:1290)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3804)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-08-09 20:17:39.223
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early for part org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early for part org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:1290)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3804)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-08-09 20:17:39.223
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early for part org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early for part org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:1290)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3804)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-08-09 20:17:39.285
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.ThreadDeath
    at jess.Jesp.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Rete.g(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Rete.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at jess.Rete.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at gov.sandia.jess.editor.model.EngineManager.createModelEngine(EngineManager.java:43)
    at gov.sandia.jess.editor.model.EngineManager.getEngine(EngineManager.java:37)
    at gov.sandia.jess.editor.model.EngineManager.clearEngine(EngineManager.java:63)
    at gov.sandia.jess.editor.model.JessModel.recomputeExpressionStarts(JessModel.java:74)
    at gov.sandia.jess.editor.model.JessModel.refreshAnnotations(JessModel.java:89)
    at gov.sandia.jess.editor.JessEditor.touch(JessEditor.java:234)
    at gov.sandia.jess.editor.JessEditor.createPartControl(JessEditor.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2942)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2764)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2019-08-09 20:17:39.738
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Quick Diff".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4168)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.getDisplay(Widget.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.quickdiff.LastSaveReferenceProvider.addElementStateListener(LastSaveReferenceProvider.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.quickdiff.LastSaveReferenceProvider.readDocument(LastSaveReferenceProvider.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.quickdiff.LastSaveReferenceProvider.getReference(LastSaveReferenceProvider.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.texteditor.quickdiff.DocumentLineDiffer$2.run(DocumentLineDiffer.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: Have you tried to read what error says? Have you verify the occurred.see log file what are the log generated inside that file? Please have a look at it and update the question with generated log.

Comment: Despite what lots of posts say deleting the .metadata is a bad thing to do as it destroys all sorts of things. Read the .log and tell us what it says. Also why are you using a version of Eclipse which is 11 releases and 8 years out of date?

Comment: I am working with jess file(.clp). it supports only that version. I also try the latest version but I couldn't find how to work with jess.

Comment: @NarthananVfc As you can see from the log, it is caused by `gov.sandia.jess.editor.JessEditor` in the UI thread. Maybe the bug only occurs with certain `.clp` files. Did you try different `.clp` files? If possible, restore the `.metadata` folder first (deleting the  `.metadata` is always a bad idea).

Comment: Did you successfully install the _jess_ plugins for _Eclipse_ as described in [Installing the JessDE](https://jessrules.com/jess/docs/70/eclipse.html)

Answer (score 0):

You’re using an expired trial version of Jess. It throws a ThreadDeath error, which is every bit as nasty as it sounds.